# When to go for a library file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I always use controller files for my project. Sometimes i get confused when to create libraries. Can you please let me know when do we create libraries files and for what purpose?

Comment: in the simplest way, think of library as the repository which makes the controller less overwhelmed. (don't take it literally, just get the gist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can simply define as following:

Controller: This entry point of your application which is associated with URI.

Helper: Helpers are written in procedural format rather than OOP format. Small scale tweaking is handled by this. As the name suggest Helper file helps the main application controllers in some ways.

Library: Libraries are conventionally reusable code which can be used over different projects.

So if you want to write a library that should be reusable and generic. or it will be a waste of time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to use any code for several portion or projects, you can create library for better understanding and easy access. Suppose, you want to use any user defined captcha generating function, you can create a library and can use it for several projects.

Answer (score 1):

When you are writing some code that is not specific to current project only and it can be reused on other projects then you should create a library.

For example, I have some generic controllers that I use in every project, I put them in libraries and load via __autoload.